# Getting "Enter Network Password" When Connecting to XP Fileshare from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking

I am Getting "Enter Network Password" When Connecting to XP Fileshare from Windows 7. When entering credentials, it fails. I can RDP into the XP machine just fine.

I have read hundreds of suggestions online and nothing is working. I am sure I am just missing something.

Here are some things I have set so far:

On Windows 7 Machine:

- homegroups is off
- password protected sharing is off
- i can RDP into the XP box
- workgroup names are the same
- network is a "work" network

On Windows XP machine:

- Simple file sharing is OFF
- Folders are shared
- Shares have the "everyone" permission, both in sharing and in NTFS permissions

What am I missing?

Comment: This isn't a "Home" edition of XP is it?

Comment: it is, and here is the caveat - it worked up until I replaced the power supply and "repaired" the xp installation plus installed SP3.

Comment: This guy had almost your exact same problem. Looks like he gave up eventually. Sorry! http://forums.techguy.org/networking/950150-solved-xp-sp3-network-access.html

Comment: Yep, I had been through that EXACT post about five times.

Answer (score 1):

I was having an identical problem and I just stumbled onto the solution for my situation: I had recently installed Virtual Box on the Win 7 machine and it installed a new network adapter.

If I **disable** the VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter on the Win 7 machine, I can access the Windows XP machine's shared folders. If I **enable** the adapter and try to access the shared XP folders, I get the "Enter Network Password" dialog.

Hope this works for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

My best attempt, good luck!

The guy on [this site](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/804e1be8-af74-4537-9729-4bae860ffc97/trouble-with-network-file-sharing-with-winxp-sp3-update-help) quotes the 897103 KB article ["You receive an "Access is denied" error message when you try to access the Shared Documents folder in Windows XP"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/897103/en-us?FR=1&PA=1&SD=HSCH):

> I seem to have solved the problem of all of the XP Home computers
>   (with SP3) on the network no longer being able to access the shares on
>   the network's one and only machine running XP Pro (with SP3) by
>   re-enabling Full Control permissions for the Shared Documents folder
>   to the Everyone account on the XP Pro machine.

Also, [this guy](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9f09d8ff-e76b-447d-9e95-5fe64eed91cf/win-xp-home-sp3-cant-access-win-7-pro-x64) has his own solution:

> Solved.  Turns out it wasn't just one XP Home workstation, it was all
>   XP Home workstations unable to connect to the server.  Must of been
>   cached on other two that seem like it was working.
>
> For other who run into this problem even though you know Win7 network
>   configuration is correct, check the network card configuration:
>
> Control Panel -> System -> Device Manager -> Network Adapters, and
>   open the network card's properties.  Under the Advanced tab, make sure
>   Flow Control and Interrupt Moderation is ENABLED!  If these are
>   disabled, Win XP Home workstations will see the server, but will error
>   with permission error when trying to connect.

Comment: So I tried all of this stuff, no luck. Also, nothing on the win 7 box has changed at all... it all worked before i repaired the xp installation.

Comment: Can you map the network share on the xp home machine?  You are mapping to itself, but use the username and password you are trying from the windows 7 machine.  Also, why are you not using simple file sharing?